# sprintf_s string format vulnerability

Tags: security, printf, string-formatting

After reading for the last few hours about string format vulnerabilities I'm still not sure if the follow code can be exploited.

[This is for challenge]

I got something like this:

```
sprintf_s(DstBuff, 0x400, "%s\n", input);
```

I'm controlling the `input` which is a string. After that `DstBuff` will be printed to the user.

If I provide input with something with length that is bigger than `0x3FF` or greater - the application crashes.

In all the articles I read it was said that `"%s"` is the safe way, but then why the app crashes?

Comment: sprintf_s should be safe provided that DstBuff is at least 0x400 in length.  I think you need to provide us more code so we can understand why your crash is happening.

Comment: I realized why the crash happening: the function checks the `input length`, if it is bigger or equal to `0x400 - 1` it throws `invalid parameter exception`... Well I can't seem to leverage this to anything useful, maybe it is not the proper attack vector.

Comment: Makes sense: [If the buffer is too small for the formatted text, including the terminating null, then the buffer is set to an empty string by placing a null character at buffer, and the invalid parameter handler is invoked.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ce3zzk1k.aspx)